# SQL Query Count and Math Operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, math, subquery

I have a unique query request.

I run this query:

```
select * from documentationissues
where dateAdded is not null
and dateAdded >= '2013-10-09 10:37:15.483'
```

This will return me however many rows have been inserted since the dateAdded clause.  What I am trying to do is do all of my math in the query as well.

I need to figure out how many minutes have passed since the dateAdded clause.
I need to get a count of how many rows that are returned.
I then need to figure out on average how many rows are being done on average per minute and then per hour.
And then say if there were 6,000,000 files to be done.  How many days it would take to process all of the files at the average day rate.

If I ran the query right now it returned 2100 results as of today at 10:56:15 am.

So that would be 19 minutes have passed which is about 110 rows per minute and about 6600 per hour.

I'm not sure how to do all of the math in the select statement with grouping etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option that also includes all of the fields you were asking for:

```
SELECT M.RowsReturned, M.MinutesPassed,
       M.RowsReturned / M.MinutesPassed AS AvgPerMinute,
       M.RowsReturned / M.MinutesPassed * 60 AS AvgPerHour,
       6000000 / M.RowsReturned  / M.MinutesPassed / 1440 AS DaysToProcess
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowsReturned, 
   DATEDIFF(minute, '2013-10-09 10:37:15.483', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS MinutesPassed
   FROM documentationissues
   WHERE dateAdded is NOT NULL
   AND dateAdded >= '2013-10-09 10:37:15.483'
) AS M
```

Comment: I like this method better, but the math on the DaysToProcess seems a bit off.  Otherwise it is working very fast and nicely.

Comment: **@James Wilson**, I do believe it should have been `/ 1440` instead of `* 1440`.  I have edited my answer.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This fixes it.  The * and the / just needed to be switched.  Thank you for the answer. :) `6000000 / M.RowsReturned * M.MinutesPassed / 1440 AS DaysToProcess`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/DATEDIFF(minute, '2013-10-09 10:37:15.483', GETDATE()) AS AvgPerMin,
        COUNT(*)/DATEDIFF(minute, '2013-10-09 10:37:15.483', GETDATE()) * 60 AS AvgPerHr
from documentationissues
where dateAdded is not null
and dateAdded >= '2013-10-09 10:37:15.483'
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me get what I needed.  I was having trouble thinking I needed to group by.  Glad to see it was much easier than I was making it out to be.